# why does jquery work differently in various browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. If jQuery is just a bunch of javascript libraries why would some
   features not work in certain browsers?
2. If the jQuery tests have
   been ran on a WebkitBased browser, can it automatically be assumed
   that all other WebkitBased browsers will have the exact same
   behavior whether mobile/desktop or other, if not what would make it
   act differently?
3. I need to automatically run jquery unit tests
   daily and track any variation in results, for visual and other
   changes how would you go about tracking these?

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support that certain features don't work in certain browsers?  one of jQuery's jobs is to abstract all the browser differences away so that you don't have to care.  There shouldn't be any features that work in one browser and not another.  If there is, it's likely a bug in your code or less likely, but still posible, a bug in jQuery.

Comment: @cwolves: that's not really true. Some functionalities are just not available in certain browsers, and jQuery says it explicitly in its documentation. This is due to limitations in javascript engines or CSS support.

Comment: @cwolves: like [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/): "this method currently does not provide cross-platform support for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does not allow data to be attached via expando properties."

Comment: @cwolves Additionally, Opera doesn't fire the "unload" event.  Found in about 20 seconds on google:  http://docs.jquery.com/Known_Issues

Comment: @ldiqual -- Never knew that, interesting... then again I never work with XML/XSLT so I'd never really need to :)  I think it's safe to say that for 95% of people, 100% of jQuery is cross-browser enough that they'll never have to care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All browsers are different and have their own javascript engine. Browsers built on the same engine (Mozilla, Webkit, etc) will work very similar, but not necessarily exactly the same.
2. No, there are some differences between mobile and desktop browsers.
3. jQuery release notes?

jQuery does an awesome job at taking care of cross browser issues. However, browsers and devices change very often, so its not likely that it will work with everything all the time.

Answer (score 2):

1) What features are you referring to? Most things will work, however there's certain limitations - IE6 just doesn't support some more modern tricks.

2) You can probably assume it, but you're best to test on each. Mobile browsers especially have different CSS behaviour sometimes.

3) I'll leave that for someone else to answer. I suspect you might get a better answer if you create a separate question, as it's a very different topic to 1 & 2